# Loop function within x and y boundaries (return to lower x after upper x iteration)

Tags: loops, unix, awk, gmt

I've got a question about forming the loop function for processing the earthquake data per bin.

Our map is as below, with the data, and runs from -125W to -114W, and 32N to 42N.

[image]

In order to process the data quickly and efficiently, we should use a loop. However, I'm not sure how to go about starting it!

We would like to sample a 1x1 degree bin, roughly as below...

- Starting in the top left corner, sample 41 to 42N and -125 to -124W
- Run calculation on sample area
- Move 1 degree East and run calculation
- repeat until at rightmost edge
- return to leftmost edge and move down a degree.

Could anyone advise on how to do this?  I'm not sure where to start, so if someone can outline a framework from which I can adapt... :)

Once we have worked out how to do it for a 1 degree bin, we can improve resolution and run our calculations :)

Comment: What programming language/library/software do you plan to use?

Comment: Hi @VadimLanda, I will be using the GMT language within a UNIX environment

Answer (score 0):

The code below nests the loops as required

```
printf "" >! loop1.txt

@ x = -125
while ($x <= -114)
    @ y = 32
    while ($y <= 42)
    printf "$x $y\n" >> loop1.txt
    @ y++
    end
@ x++
end2
```

and produces an output of

```
x1 y1
x1 y2
x1 y3
x2 y1
x2 y2
x2 y3
```

etc.

Required now, however, is to integrate an awk command during the second loop, to create a third column output